# document.reference.removeChild() doesn't works correctly. How can I fix that?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, asp.net-core

```js
  var ausgelöst = false;
    var zuerst = 0;
    more.addEventListener("blur", function () {
        var anzahl = document.querySelector("#more").value;
        if (!ausgelöst) {
            for (var i = 0; i < anzahl; i++) {

                hier.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                    '<br><label name="Mails" class="form-label"></label><input type="email" class="form-control" name="Mails" placeholder="name@example.com" required><span name="Mails" class="text-danger"><br>')
                hier.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                    '<label name="Mails" class="form-label"></label><input type="date" class="form-control" name="Mails" placeholder="dd.mm.jjjj" required><span name="Mails" class="text-danger"></span><br>')
            }
            ausgelöst = true;

        }
        else {
            if (zuerst < anzahl) {
                for (var i = 0; i < (anzahl - zuerst); i++) {
                    hier.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                        '<br><label name="Mails" class="form-label"></label> <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Mails" placeholder="name@example.com" required> <span name="Mails" class="text-danger"></span>')
                    hier.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                        '<br><label name="Mails" class="form-label"></label> <input type="date" class="form-control" name="Mails" placeholder="dd.mm.jjjj" required> <span name="Mails" class="text-danger"></span><br>')

                }

            }
            else {

                for (var i = document.getElementById("hier").childElementCount; i > anzahl+1; i--) {
                  
                    document.getElementById("hier").removeChild(document.getElementById("hier").children[i-1]);
                    

                }
            

                
            }
        }
        zuerst = anzahl;
    })
```

```html
<form asp-action="Testview" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="needs-validation" novalidate>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10"></div>

        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="more">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group mb-3" id="myTextField">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="putMoreFields">
            </div>

            <div id="hier">
                
            </div>


            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="weiter" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4"></div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="~/Home/" role="button">Abbrechen</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        </div>


</form>
```

i add fields with following code.

```
 if (!ausgelöst) {
        for (var i = 0; i < anzahl; i++) {

            hier.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                '<label name="Mails" class="form-label"></label> <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Mails" placeholder="name@example.com" required> <span name="Mails" class="text-danger"></span> </div> <div class="invalid-feedback"> Bitte geben Sie eine Mail-Adresse ein. </div> </div >')
            hier.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                '<label name="Mails" class="form-label"></label> <input type="date" class="form-control" name="Mails" placeholder="dd.mm.jjjj" required> <span name="Mails" class="text-danger"></span> </div> <div class="invalid-feedback"> Bitte geben Sie eine Mail-Adresse ein. </div> </div ><br>')
        }
        ausgelöst = true;

    }
```

(Mails is a list).

In the form the user can enter a number and gets these amount of new fields. If the user enters a smaler number the difference between the old and new amount should be deleted.

I try to use this code:

```
 for (var i = document.getElementById("hier").childElementCount; i >= anzahl + 1; i--) {               
                document.getElementById("hier").removeChild(document.getElementById("hier").children[i-1]);
            }
```

The code doesn't work correctly. It deletes less fields.

Can someone help me?

Best regards

JuRi-2020

Comment: Please create a complete snippet with tools `<>`

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are meaning @SimoneRossaini. I add some code.

Comment: @JuRi-2020 See [How to create Stack Snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212).

Comment: Hi @JuRi-2020, Please explain more about your scenario . What do you mean for `the difference between the old and new amount should be deleted.`, which code will explain for this requirement?

Comment: The user can enter a number in the input field with the id="more". Than he leave the field and an eventlistener was add with a function. This function add new fields. For example the user enter 3 but he want only two fields. So in the next step the user enters 2 in the input field with the id="more". The goal is, that the fields that aren't use anymore are deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. It doesn't work with the snippet above but with the origin project.
I changed the code to:

```
else {
            var parent = document.getElementById("hier");
            var i = parent.childElementCount;
            while (i > 0) {
                if (parent.childElementCount == anzahl*9) {
                    break;
                }
                parent.removeChild(parent.children[i - 1]);
                
                i--;
            }
        }
```

I multiply the entered number with the amount of childs which are added by each iteration.
It isn't the best solution because it's hard coded but for my project it's working.

Thanks.

Best regards

JuRi-2020

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order it's removed, I would do this:

```
const hier = document.getElementById('hier');

// checks if it's more than needed
if (hier.children.length > anzahl) {
    // Number to remove
    const remove = hier.children.length - anzahl;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < remove; i++) {
        hier.children[i].remove(); // Basically removeChild but less references, it references the node itself
    }
}
```